# Show decimal if needed In odoo pos ticker

Tags: odoo-12, pos

How can I remove trailing zeroes from a floating point number? Ex: If my number is 1.000, it should display 1 and if the quantity is 1.250, it should show only 1.25.

I tried to change it from *Settings -> Database Structure -> Decimal Accuracy* with Digits after `comma=0`, but I won't be able to sell a product with a quantity of 0.5.

Comment: Please specify the programming language you are using.

Comment: You can alter the corresponding template to remove the trailing zeros.